# How to read file and put in an array

Tags: c++, file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr[3][2];
    int i =0,j=0;
    ofstream out ("test1.dat" , ios::app);
    string name;
    while(true)
    {
        cin>>name;
        if(name=="end")
        break;
        out << name <<' ' ;

    }
    out.close();

    ifstream in ("test1.dat", ios::in);
    in >> name;
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        arr[i][j]=name;
        in>>name;
        j++;
        arr[i][j]=name;
        i++;
        j=0;

    }
    in.close();
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){

    cout<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){

            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";}
        }

    return 0;
}
```

please help i have run-time error with this.what is my problem?i want to write some data in a file then read them and put them in an array and then print the array.i want to write and read the file by string not by character.sorry about my weak english.
thanks

Comment: This is not `C`, BTW.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C man. As for your issue: have you made sure the streams are created successfully? You don't seem to be checking the state bits.

Comment: More than likely `i` is becoming greater than 2 in your reading while loop.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: Search for existing "almost" duplicates:  "stackoverflow c++ read file array".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a condition for i in your while loop. 
This fixes your run-time error with the array bounds but you still have a logic error (unless you want duplicate occurrences of the same word in your array?)

```
while(!in.eof() && i < 3)
{
    arr[i][j]=name;
    in>>name;
    j++;
    arr[i][j]=name;
    i++;
    j=0;
}
```